# Need to match values from two different columns and then print out values from a corresponding column

Tags: python, csv

I need to match the values from two columns, but then output the value from a separate column that alines with only one of the original columns.

Here is an example of the spreadsheet I am trying to get info from:

```
Unique_ID, fullname, role, students_needed
1234, john doe, student, tim young
5678, steven tyler, student, john doe
9101, sarah joe, student, ashley fonz
2758, ashley fonz, student, rick rose
```

If I needed to figure out what students from 'student_needed' were in the 'fullname' column and then print out the 'Unique_ID' of those student, how would I do it?

Here is the code that I have so far that I am using from a different csv project, but I can't seem to change it to make it work. It keeps printing vertical, but it isn't printing the correct information either.

```
  1 # 1. Match Student full name with CAMS Students
  2 # 2. Match Match Schoology ID with CAMS Students
  3 # 3. Match instructor ID with Schoology ID
  4 # 4. create new csv file with student ID matched with instructor ID
  5 
  6 import os
  7 import csv
  8 from itertools import groupby
  9 from operator import itemgetter
 10 
 11 path = "/Users/brandon/desktop/"
 12 
 13 writers = {}
 14  
 15 with open(os.path.join(path, "Schoology_Unique_IDs.csv"), "rbU") as rosters:
 16 
 17     reader = csv.DictReader(rosters)
 18     headers = reader.fieldnames
 19     
 20     for row in reader:
 21         if not all(row): continue
 22         fullname = row['Full Name']
 23         Schoology_ID = row['Unique User ID']
 24         CAMS_Student = row['CAMS Students']
 25         Teacher = row['Teacher Name']
 26         for row in fullname:
 27             for row in CAMS_Student:
 28                 if row == row:
 29                     print row
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution just using standard libraries? For instance this could easily be solved using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) like so: `df[df['students_needed'].isin(df['fullname'])]['Unique_ID']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it. Read the file once to get the proper name, id relationship in a dictionary, then do it again to match names with keys.

```
import csv
with open("Schoology_Unique_IDs.csv","rbU") as f1, open("Schoology_Unique_IDs.csv","rbU") as f2:
    r1 = csv.reader(f1)
    r1.next() 
    d = {r[1]:r[0] for r in r1}
    r2 = csv.reader(f2)    
    print "\n".join([d[i[3]] for i in r2 if i[3] in d])
```

This prints:

```
1234
2758
```